# Validation of JSON schema 'oneOf' fails unittest assertRaisesRegex

Tags: json, jsonschema, python-3.6, assertraises

On using Python3.6 unittest `assertRaisesRegex` to validate some JSON there are differences in the output generated between validating code under the JSON `oneOf` keyword and code that is not. I am testing the removal of `required` properties.

The problem is that the user expects one type of error message but another is received and `assertRaisesRegex` fails as it does not match the regex.

Using http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com to validate the JSON I see the actual error message expected has been nested deeper.

I can get around the problem by searching for the new message when testing for `oneOf` properties, but want to know if there is a better way to handle this problem that is consistent with my other tests, i.e. using the same format for the messages I expect?

Below are some examples of output that test for `required` JSON properties being removed. The expected message format is marked with a `=>` the unexpected with `**`

Example 1 (`herokuapp.com`): When a `required` property is removed (not under `oneOf`)

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/Attr_B"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/Attr_B"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "required",
=>"message" : "object has missing required properties ([\"alpha\"])",
  "required" : [ "alpha", "beta" ],
  "missing" : [ "alpha" ]
} ]
```

Example 2 (`herokuapp.com`): When a `oneOf` nested `required` property is removed

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/Attr_B/properties/beta"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/Attr_B/beta"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "oneOf",
**"message" : "instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 1)",
  "matched" : 0,
  "nrSchemas" : 1,
  "reports" : {
    "/properties/Attr_B/properties/beta/oneOf/0" : [ {
      "level" : "error",
      "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : "/properties/Attr_B/properties/beta/oneOf/0"
      },
      "instance" : {
        "pointer" : "/Attr_B/beta"
      },
      "domain" : "validation",
      "keyword" : "required",
=>    "message" : "object has missing required properties ([\"min_percentage\"])",
      "required" : [ "max_percentage", "min_percentage" ],
      "missing" : [ "min_percentage" ]
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

Within my unittests using `jsonschema`, the messages differ but the problem is the same.

Example 1 (`jsonschema`): When a `required` property is removed (not under `oneOf`)

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_valid__JSON_against_schema (__main__.SchemaTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in test_valid__JSON_against_schema
    validate(test_json, test_schema)
  File "/local_scratch/tools/PACKAGES/Python-3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/local_scratch/tools/PACKAGES/Python-3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
=>  jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'alpha' is a required property

Failed validating 'required' in schema['properties']['Attr_B']:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'alpha': {'enum': ['a', 'b'], 'type': 'string'},
                    'beta': {'oneOf': [{'additionalProperties': False,
                                        'properties': {'max_percentage': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                                                          'maximum': 150,
                                                                          'minimum': 10,
                                                                          'type': 'integer'},
                                                       'min_percentage': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                                                          'maximum': 50,
                                                                          'minimum': 1,
                                                                          'type': 'integer'}},
                                        'required': ['min_percentage',
                                                     'max_percentage'],
                                        'type': 'object'}]}},
     'required': ['alpha', 'beta'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance['Attr_B']:
    {'beta': {'max_percentage': 24, 'min_percentage': 24}}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Example 2 (`jsonschema`): When a `oneOf` nested `required` property is removed

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_valid__JSON_against_schema (__main__.SchemaTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in test_valid__JSON_against_schema
    validate(test_json, test_schema)
  File "/local_scratch/tools/PACKAGES/Python-3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/local_scratch/tools/PACKAGES/Python-3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
**  jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: {'max_percentage': 24} is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['Attr_B']['properties']['beta']:
    {'oneOf': [{'additionalProperties': False,
                'properties': {'max_percentage': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                                  'maximum': 150,
                                                  'minimum': 10,
                                                  'type': 'integer'},
                               'min_percentage': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                                  'maximum': 50,
                                                  'minimum': 1,
                                                  'type': 'integer'}},
                'required': ['min_percentage', 'max_percentage'],
                'type': 'object'}]}

On instance['Attr_B']['beta']:
    {'max_percentage': 24}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I am validating against this schema

```
{
    "id": "a-schema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "my schema",

    "type": "object",
    "properties": {

        "Attr_A": {

            "type": "integer",
            "minimum" : 1,
            "maximum" : 200,
            "additionalProperties": false            
        },

        "Attr_B": {

            "type": "object",
            "properties": {

                "alpha": {

                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["a", "b"]
                },

                "beta": {

                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {

                                "min_percentage": {

                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "minimum" : 1,
                                    "maximum" : 50,
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                },

                                "max_percentage": {

                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "minimum" : 10,
                                    "maximum" : 150,
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false,
                            "required": ["min_percentage", "max_percentage"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },

            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": ["alpha", "beta"]
        },

        "Attr_C": {

            "type": "object",
            "properties": {

                "min_percentage": {

                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum" : 1,
                    "maximum" : 50,
                    "additionalProperties": false
                },

                "max_percentage": {

                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum": 10,
                    "maximum": 150,
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            },

            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": ["min_percentage", "max_percentage"]
        }
    },

    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["Attr_A", "Attr_B", "Attr_C"]
}
```

Here is my instance data

```
{
    "Attr_A": 123,

    "Attr_B": {

        "alpha": "a",

        "beta": {

             "min_percentage": 20,
             "max_percentage": 24
        }
    },

    "Attr_C": {

         "min_percentage": 20,
         "max_percentage": 24    
    }
}
```

These are my tests

```
with open("schema.json") as schema_file:
    test_schema = json.load(schema_file)
schema_file.close()

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    test_json = json.load(json_file)
json_file.close()

### Test the whole JSON is valid against the Schema
def test_valid__JSON_against_schema(self):
    global test_schema
    global test_json
    validate(test_json, test_schema)

### 'Attr_B.alpha' test
def test_missing__Attr_B_alpha(self):
    global test_schema
    global test_json
    dict_copy = copy.deepcopy(test_json)
    dict_copy.pop("alpha")
    msg = "'alpha' is a required property"
    with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValidationError, msg):        
        validate(dict_copy, test_schema)

### 'Attr_B.beta.min_percentage' test
def test_missing__Attr_B_beta_min_percentage(self):
    global test_schema
    global test_json
    dict_copy = copy.deepcopy(test_json)
    test_info = dict_copy["Attr_B"]
    beta= test_info["beta"]
    beta.pop("min_percentage")
    msg = "'min_percentage' is a required property"
    with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValidationError, msg):        
        validate(dict_copy, test_schema)
```